# Proxmox LXC networking

Tags: networking, php, lxc, proxmox, ovh

We have 5 physical machines hosted at OVH. Each of them have Proxmox 5.2-10 installed 
Machines are inside of OVH vRack.
we have separate LXC for database, separate LXC with loadbalancer and several separate instances with our web application stack (php and nginx).

When we put more LXCs with our web stack on a single physical machine after a while all of them except one just stuck. 
PHP nor nginx are not responding on the network. Load average on the physical server suddenly starts to grow. 
It is possible to enter the LXC via ssh or pct enter but impossible to shutdown from Proxmox web interface, LXC process has to be forcefully killed.

This problem started to appear when we upgraded PHP from 7.0 to 7.2. I don't think that it could be somehow related but I've never experienced simillar behaviour before.
So far we weren't able to come up with any solution except keeping the web LXCs on separate machines.
LXCs which do not have our web app stack can be normally together on one physical machine.

We believe that it has to do something with networking. Some files are shared via NFS on all LXCs. Could this be a hint? But again the problem is only on web LXCs. Other container with shared files can normaly work together.

Example configration of LXC network interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
iface lo inet6 loopback
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
# Include files from /etc/network/interfaces.d:
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet static
        address 5.39.56.172
        netmask 255.255.255.224
        gateway 5.39.56.190
auto eth1
iface eth1 inet static
        address 172.16.32.172
        netmask 255.240.0.0
```

Example configuration of host machine interfaces:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

iface eno1 inet manual

auto eno2
iface eno2 inet manual

auto vmbr0
iface vmbr0 inet static
        address  147.135.254.187
        netmask  255.255.255.0
        gateway  147.135.254.254
        bridge-ports eno1
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0

iface vmbr0 inet6 static
        address  2001:41d0:303:2dbb::
        netmask  64

auto vmbr1
iface vmbr1 inet static
        address  172.16.35.1
        netmask  255.240.0.0
        broadcast  172.31.255.255
        bridge-ports eno2
        bridge-stp off
        bridge-fd 0
        network 172.16.0.0
```

Comment: Are the prox servers in a cluster? If yes, check musticast traffic. I had this exact issue with a cluster of 20 prox 5 servers and it turned out to be a blown switch and multicast was flooding the network.

Comment: need way more information, we have no idea what your running on these for one other than pve, php and nginx. theres thousaands of things that could be wrong including pve itself. I've had a lot of issues myself with the 5.x and about to switch back to 4.x, but i've been having containers show up greyed out with a ? on them for example, other people have been having nodes in a cluster just stop suddenly etc, but need way more info if you want help on this